# Logic behind adding dates in C

Tags: c, date, logic

I want to add x number of days to a date. 
Can someone help me with my logic especially in adding x number of days to a specific date.
It seems to work for small number of days added but if I add a large number of days, it starts to give really funny answers.

Also no functions please, just logic.

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


int dd, mm, yyyy, daysthismonth, days, option;

printf("Please enter a date in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy:\n");
if(scanf("%d/%d/%d",&dd,&mm,&yyyy)!= 3){
    printf("Please enter a valid date\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

/* Calculating days in a month */
}
if((mm == 4)|| (mm == 6) || (mm == 9) || (mm == 11)){
    daysthismonth = 30;
}

else if((mm == 2)){
    if((yyyy%4 == 0) && ( (yyyy%100 == 0) || (yyyy%400 == 0))){
        daysthismonth = 29;
    }
    else{
        daysthismonth = 28;
    }
}

else {
    daysthismonth = 31;
}

/* Calculating the validity of User Input */
if( (dd<0) || (dd>daysthismonth) || (mm<0) || (mm>12) || (yyyy < 0) || (yyyy>9999) ){
    printf("Plase enter a valid date between from a day from 0 AD to 9999 AD\n.");
}

printf("Todays date:        %02d/%02d/%04d\n"
        "How many days would you like to go in the future? \n",dd,mm,yyyy);
    if(scanf("%d",&days) != 1){
        printf("Please enter a valid input\n");
    }
    printf("The date %d days in the future is:\n",days); 

    while(days > (daysthismonth - dd)){
        mm = mm + 1;
        days = days - (daysthismonth - dd);

        if( days < daysthismonth){
            dd = days;
        }

        if( mm>12){
        mm = 1;
        yyyy = yyyy + 1; 
        }

    }   

    dd = dd + days;

    }

    printf("            %02d/%02d/%04d\n",dd,mm,yyyy);  

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

I guess my logic was if you added a large number of days, it would subtract the next month's days until you get to a point where the days to be added is less than the days in the month. At that point the date can just be the days you have to add.

That's why I implemented a while? loop so it could reiterate

edited: scanf() != 1

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Why do you perform some calculations and then validate user input?  Validate should come first. Regardless of the outcome, you use the input.

Comment: No functions?  They were created to _organize_ one's thoughts in C!

Comment: Don't understand your `while` loop at all. Surely there's some bugs in there.

Comment: I guess my logic was if you added a large number of days, it would subtract the next month's days until you get to a point where the days to be added is less than the days in the month. At that point the date can just be the days you have to add

Comment: @Pyrons: Yes, but you're using days*this*month - dd, not days*that*month.

Comment: Also, your leap year boolean expression is wrong. One of the `==` should be `!=`. And there is a stray close brace which generates various compile errors.

Comment: @rici so i need to define a daysthatmonth?

Comment: If you use your approach, you have to deal with the length of every month between the start date and the target.

Comment: @pyrons: do it with a pencil and a piece of paper and you'll see the problem. The best way of learning to program is to start by learning how to be a computer :)

Comment: @rici I traced the logic and what I found is that I need to reiterate what's in the while loop until my number of days becomes less than the days in the month. I was wondering if the while loop is the correct way to do this

Comment: @pyrons: while is fine. But the number of days in the month varies from month to month, so you can't just calculate it once. Use a function.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to add days on a date.

The easy logic is to convert the date to days, add the x days, then convert days to date.

The complex logic is to just make the add like in maths

```
 yyyy/mm/dd
+        dd
-----------
     result
```

like in the maths the numbers can only be from 0-9 here the date / month / year have to be valid based on the rest.

converting the days you want to add to date before the add and then add before making valid can help.

**Example in javascript (so that you can easy run it on the browser's console)**:

```
function daysInMonth(month,year){
    // Does not matter how you make this function
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

var year = 2014;
var month = 8;
var day = 8;
var daysToAdd = 123434;

day += daysToAdd;

var maxDay = daysInMonth( month, year);
while( day>maxDay ){

    day -= maxDay;
    month += 1;
    if(month==13){
        month = 1;
        year += 1;
    }

    maxDay = daysInMonth( month, year);
}

console.log(day+'/'+month+'/'+year);
```

It works like a charm :)

**C code (After a request) :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    // Init the variables we use
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;
    int maxDay = 0;
    int daysToAdd = 0;

    // Ask user for a date
    printf("Please enter a date in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy:\n");
    // Validate data
    while( scanf( "%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year)!= 3 || day<=0 || month<=0 || year<0 || daysInMonth(month,year)<day ){
        printf("Please enter a valid date.\n");
    }

    // Ask user for days to add
    printf("Please enter days to add: \n");
    // Validate data
    while( scanf( "%d", &daysToAdd)!= 1 || daysToAdd<=0 ){
        printf("Please enter a positive number.\n");
    }

    // Calculate date

    day += daysToAdd;
    maxDay = daysInMonth( month, year);
    while( day>maxDay ){

        day -= maxDay;
        month += 1;
        if(month==13){
            month = 1;
            year += 1;
        }

        maxDay = daysInMonth( month, year);
    }

    printf("Result date : %d/%d/%d", day, month, year);

    return(0);
}

// Get days in the month
int daysInMonth( int month, int year){
    if( month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11 ){
        return 30;
    }else if( month== 2 ){
        if( year%4==0 && ( year%100==0 || year%400==0) )
            return 29;
        else
            return 28;
    }else{
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Online test link : http://ideone.com/CGXgtP

Happy coding.

Comment: If you add a large number of days you can't just keep on adding. You need to take on the next month's number of days and that can also depend on the year you in (leap year/not leap year).

Comment: Yes i agree. The same as adding 2 on 09 = 11. A 1 appears.

Comment: How do I get it to work in C? I don't really get the daysinmonth(month, year) ...

Comment: Cool thanks; In the end I had this:                                             .                       while(days > (daysthismonth - dd)){
   mm = mm + 1;
   days = days - (daysthismonth);
  
   if( mm>12){
   mm = 1;
   yyyy = yyyy + 1; 
   } 
  }  
  dd = dd + days;

Answer (score 1):

Just store your day/month/year into a `struct tm`, call `mktime()` on it to convert to epoch seconds, add `days*24*60*60` to advance it, then call `localtime_r()` (or `localtime()`) on the result to get day/month/year again.

Be mindful of daylight saving time: you should probably set the hours component to noon to avoid any possibility of gaining or losing a day when DST changes.

Comment: OP is trying to develop the logic himself/herself.